# What is the srcset attribute in an IMG tag and how to use it?

Tags: html, srcset

I want to know how could I start using the HTML `srcset` img attribute in my mobile apps. Or Is there any other jQuery plugin which helps me to solve image resolution problem.

```
<img srcset="banner-HD.jpeg 2x, banner-phone.jpeg 100w, banner-phone-HD.jpeg 100w 2x" 
     alt="Banner Image" />
```

Answer (score 49):

In short, `Srcset` is a new attribute which allows you to specify different kind of images for different screen-sizes/orientation/display-types. The usage is really simple, you just provide a lot of different images separating them with a comma like this: `<img src="image.jpg" alt="image" srcset="<img> <descriptor>, ..., <img_n> <descriptor_n>">`. Here is an example: `srcset="image.jpg 160w, image2.jpg 320w, image3.jpg 2x"`

---

This is a longer answer which explains things in more details.

**Difference between srcset and picture**. Both `srcset` and `picture` does approximately the same things, but there is a subtle difference: `picture` dictates what image the browser should use, whereas `srcset` gives the browser a choice. A lot of things can be used to select this choice like viewport size, users preferences, network condition and so on. The support for `srcset` is pretty good and [almost all current browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset) more or less support it. Situation with a `picture` element is a [little bit worse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=picture).

**Descriptors** are just a way to show what kind of image is hidden behind the resource. There are various kinds of descriptors:

- **density descriptor**. `srcset="image.jpg, image-2X.jpg 2x"`
  The display density values—the 1x, 2x, etc.—are referred to as display density descriptors. If a display density descriptor isn’t provided, it is assumed to be 1x. Good variant to target retina displays.
- **width descriptor**. `srcset="image-240.jpg 240w, image-640.jpg 640w"`. I am sure this is self explanatory. The only problem is that by itself width descriptor is not really helpful. [Why? read here](http://blog.cloudfour.com/responsive-images-101-part-4-srcset-width-descriptors/)
- **size descriptor**, which only makes sense if you use width descriptor. `srcset="image-160.jpg 160w, image-320.jpg 320w, image-640.jpg 640w, image-1280.jpg 1280w" sizes="(max-width: 480px) 100vw, (max-width: 900px) 33vw, 254px">`. The instructions for the browser would look like this: `(max-width: 480px) 100vw` — if the viewport is 480 pixels wide or smaller, the image will be 100% of the viewport width. `(max-width: 900px) 33vw` — if the viewport is 480 pixels wide or smaller, this rule will never be reached because of the previous media condition. And 254px is when there is no media condition listed, the length is assumed to be a default value used when none of the other media conditions are met.

Just for completeness will add here that there is an [image-set()](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-image-set) attribute for a background image in CSS and some other helpful link [here](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2015/08/the-state-of-responsive-images/)

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-srcset): "It is incorrect to mix width descriptors and pixel density descriptors in the same srcset attribute." This is also stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26937237/12917821).

Comment: @SalvadorDali What determines which picture is selected (when using `sizes` attribute)?

Answer (score 10):

Here is a [detailed guide on srcset](https://imagekit.io/responsive-images/#chapter-4---srcset) along with code samples.

`srcset` allows you to define a list of different image resources along with size information so that browser can pick the most appropriate image based on the actual device’s resolution.

Each comma-separated item in `srcset` has:

1. Image URL, e.g. `http://ik.imagekit.io/demo/default-image.jpg` or relative path `/demo/default-image.jpg`
2. An empty space
3. The actual width of the image or display density:

   - Either using display density descriptor, for example, `1.5x`, `2x` etc.
   - Or, using width descriptors, for example, `450w`. This is the width of the image in pixels.

### Using display density descriptor

The syntax for display density descriptors is straightforward. `srcset` provides a comma-separated list of image resources along with display density it should be used, for example`1x`, `2x` etc.

```html
<img src="image.jpg" 
     srcset="image.jpg,
             image_2x.jpg 2x"
/>
```

Live demo - https://imagekitio.github.io/responsive-images-guide/srcset-density.html.

### Using width descriptor

The syntax is similar to the display density descriptor, but instead of display density values, we provide the actual width of the image.

```html
<img src="image.jpg" 
     srcset="small.jpg 300w,
             medium.jpg 600w,
             large.jpg 900w"
/>
```

**This lets the browser pick the best image**

Using width descriptor allows the browser to pick the best candidate from `srcset` based on the actual width needed to render that image on that particular display at runtime.

Note that display pixel density is also taken into account by the browser while calculating the required width.

For example, assuming an image takes up the whole viewport width - On a 300px wide screen with DPR 2, the browser will pick `medium.jpg` because it needs a 300x2=600px wide image. On a 300px wide screen with DPR value 3, the browser will select `large.jpg` because it needs a 300x3=900px wide image.

**Demo - srcset with width descriptor**

Let see this in action with a live demo - https://imagekitio.github.io/responsive-images-guide/srcset-width.html.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a good article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/high-dpi/#toc-srcset) on the `srcset` attribute and how to use it. `srcet` allows you to declare a set of images to be displayed on different viewport sizes. You just have to save and image at different resolutions e.g. banner-phone-HD.jpeg would be the highest resolution.

Exmaple:

```
<img alt="my awesome image"
src="banner.jpeg"
srcset="banner-HD.jpeg 2x, banner-phone.jpeg 640w, banner-phone-HD.jpeg 640w 2x">
```

The above would serve banner-phone.jpeg to devices with viewport width under 640px, banner-phone-HD.jpeg to small screen high DPI devices, banner-HD.jpeg to high DPI devices with screens greater than 640px, and banner.jpeg to everything else.

There are also other methods like CSS media queries you can use to produce the same effect.

I am not aware of any JQuery plugins which would help with this.

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-srcset): "It is incorrect to mix width descriptors and pixel density descriptors in the same srcset attribute." This is also stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26937237/12917821).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify different image resources by using the srcset and sizes attributes on img or source elements. These aid a user agent in selecting the best image source to show.

Images that the browser might serve up are made possible by the srcset attribute alone. The user agent chooses which image to display based on the specifics of the device, while the author should supply a comma-separated list of images.

For example:
Pixel density is defined by adding an x to the image density number:

```
<img src="example1.png"
     srcset="example2.png 2x, example3.png 3x, example4.png 4x">
```

Note that the image defined with the src attribute is estimated to be 1x. As for the image width, we should add a w to the pixel width number:

```
<img src="example1.png"
     srcset="example2.png 100w, example3.png 500w, example4.png 1000w">
```

Remember that using the sizes attribute requires using the srcset attribute's width variant.

You could read more about how to use the srcset attribute and make the [responsive image here](https://blog.scaleflex.com/responsive-image-and-plugins/) where they list very details.