# Is it possible to upload the images of different width on different screens

Tags: html, css, image

I want to upload images in mulitple sizes.

For example
If I am viewing the site in mobile (320px) the image with the width of 320px be shown .
If I am viewing the site in Desktop the resolution of the image should be 1024 px

Note: I dont want to set the width using css I actually want to use different images based on the screen resolution so I can get maximum score in page speed insights

o basically what I need to have following functionality

If the screensize is 1024 we need to load image 1 with width 1024
If the screensize is 760 we need to load image 2 with width 760
If the screensize is 320 we need to load image 3 with width 320
and vice versa

Comment: Look at srcset , it will do what you need.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634463/what-is-an-srcset-attribute-in-img-tag-and-how-to-use-it?r=SearchResults

Comment: You can specify multiple sizes as @G-Cyrillus has suggested, but bear in mind that you'll never be able to specify enough images to satisfy all potential viewport dimensions so you'll also want to do something like specify cover or contain on the img or background.

Comment: Is it possible I can get only 1 image in source. Using above will show 3 different images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the  tag to define several sources based on media queries in your HTML. This will load up different image file based on the screen size without the need for CSS at all.

For example:

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width:1024px)" srcset="./image1024.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width:760px)" srcset="./image760.jpg">
  <img src="./image320.jpg">
</picture>
```

The last  tag is behaving like the default image will be shown if no media queries were good.

[Link to definition and usage of  on W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_picture.asp)

Answer (score -1):

You Can Set

```
#image-tag:background-size: 100%;
```

so that image width is equal to screen width.

Comment: I did not want to use CSS